# ADS simulation error when inputting a clock in to a D flip-flop through an NMOS switch

Tags: simulation, clock, nmos, ads

A NMOS gate controls when the clock signal is fed into the clock of the D flip-flop.

Below is the NMOS gate schematic and simulation. As we can see, the Vsquare only goes through the NMOS when the gate voltage Vstep2 is high. No problem!

[image]

[image]

But if I connect this clock signal to the D flip-flop, it gives me a simulation error at 50 nm.

[image]

[image]

Now the tricky thing is that if I give the D flip-flop the clock signal directly without the NMOS gate, the simulation works fine without any error.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can make some tweak to avoid the simulation error when sending the clock signal to the D flip-flop through an NMOS gate?

Comment: What if you make it an AND gate instead of a transistor?

Comment: Try adding series resistance to `Vsquare` ?  Like 25ohm or something.